# Prove that random variables satisfy the inequality $E(XY)^2 \le E(X^2)E(Y^2)$?

Tags: probability, inequality

Given Random variables $X$ and $Y$ is it true always that;

$$E(XY)^2 \le  E(X^2)E(Y^2)$$

Is it easy to prove?

Comment: You may want to look up the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: A technicality: You need the LHS to be well-defined in the first place, which it might not be even though the RHS always is.

Comment: If $X$ or $Y$ uses the Cauchy distribution, the RHS may not be defined either.

Comment: @cardinal: Cauchy-Schwarz implies that the left side is well-defined whenever the right side is finite.

Comment: @Robert: Of course that's true, but that's not the point! (The RHS need *not* be finite and, yet, in certain such cases CS will still hold and in others the RHS will be well-defined and the LHS will not.)

Comment: @Mario: As long as $X$ and $Y$ are *random variables* (i.e., measurable), the RHS is *always* well-defined. It simply need not be finite (your Cauchy example, for instance).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean
$$(E(XY))^2 \le  E(X^2)E(Y^2).$$
One way to prove this is to realize it's a special case of the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality.

Here's another.  Let
\begin{align}
f(t) = {} & E((tX+Y)^2) \\[8pt]
= {} & (E(X^2)) t^2 + 2(E(XY))t + E(Y^2) \\[8pt]
= {} & at^2 + bt + c.
\end{align}
where $t$ is "constant", i.e. not random.  Clearly $E((tX+Y)^2)\ge0$ for all real values of $t$.  Now recall that for real $a,b,c$, the polynomial $at^2 + bt+c$ remains non-negative as $t$ changes if and only if $a\ge0$ and the discriminant $b^2-4ac\le0$.  So
$$
b^2-4ac = 4E(XY)^2 - 4E(X^2)E(Y^2).
$$
So
$$
4(E(XY)^2 - E(X^2)E(Y^2))\le0.
$$
Divide both sides by $4$ and there you have it.

Comment: This is a nice proof of Cauchy Schwarz.  I had forgotten about that one.

Comment: A concise proof. make very senseeee^_^

Answer (score 3):

The expectation of a product of random variables is an inner product, to which you can apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and obtain exactly that inequality. Hence the answer is yes.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Probability_theory

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the [Cauchy Schwarz inequality for Random Variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Probability_theory).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following should work for discrete random variables at least.

$$
\mathbb{E}[XY] = \sum_{x, y}x \times y \times p(x,y) = \sum_{x,y} (\sqrt{p(x,y)}.x) \times (\sqrt{p(x,y)}.y)
$$
$$
 \sum_{x,y} (\sqrt{p(x,y)}.x) \times (\sqrt{p(x,y)}.y) \leq \sqrt{\sum_{x,y}p(x,y).x^2} \sqrt{\sum_{x,y}p(x,y).y^2} = \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[Y^2]}
$$
where we just simply used standard Cauchy Schwarz.
Therefore we have

$$\mathbb{E}[XY] \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[Y^2]}$$

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, since it only adresses discrete random variables.

Comment: Indeed @VincentBatens, I started off saying that as well. I am unsure of the moderation here: is this considered a completely invalid response? I believe this can still be a good starting point.

Comment: Usually you want to answer questions completely and if you only can answer part of it, people usually leave a comment instead.

Comment: Oh okay, it'll become too cluttered in a comment. For now, I will leave it as is. Happy to take it down in case there are many who find it like you. Thanks.

Comment: Nah you can leave it up, just keep that in mind for the next answer.