# $\Pr[X > 0] \geq \frac{E[X]^2}{E[X^2]}$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, inequality, random-variables, expectation

Given $X$ is a finite non-negative discrete random variable that is not equal to identical zero. Prove that $$\Pr[X > 0] \geq \frac{E[X]^2}{E[X^2]}$$

My attempt:

$$\Pr[X > 0] = \sum_{i = 1}^n\Pr[X = i]$$

$$E[X]^2 = \left(\sum_{i = 0}^n \Pr[X = i] \cdot i\right)^2$$

$$E[X^2] = \sum_{i = 0}^n \Pr[X = i]\cdot i^2$$

$$\Pr[X > 0] \cdot E[X^2] \geq E[X]^2 \iff \sum_{i = 1}^n\Pr[X = i] \cdot \sum_{i = 0}^n \Pr[X = i]\cdot i^2 \geq \left(\sum_{i = 0}^n \Pr[X = i] \cdot i\right)^2$$

$$\left( \Pr[X = 1] + \dotso +\Pr[X = n]\right)\cdot \left( \Pr[X = 0] \cdot 0 + \Pr[X = 1] \cdot 1^2+ \dotso + \Pr[X = n] \cdot n^2\right) \geq \left( \Pr[X = 0] \cdot 0 + \Pr[X = 1] \cdot  1 + \dotso \Pr[X = n] \cdot n\right)^2$$

Also notice that $\Pr[X = i] = \Pr[X  = j], \ i \neq j$, here I'm not sure about $\Pr[X = i] = \frac{1}{n}$ or $\Pr[X = i] = \frac{1}{n + 1}$, because of $0$ (intuitively it should be $\frac{1}{n + 1}$), but I think in this problem I don't need the exact value of $\Pr[X = i]$, so let $\forall i \ \Pr[X = i] = p$

$$n \cdot p (p + 4p + 9p + \dotso +n^2p ) \geq (p + 2p + \dotso + np)^2$$

What should I do next?

Comment: It is not true that $P(X=i)=1/n$, for instance when $X$ is a binomial(n,p).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$X$ may not be discrete, so your argument does not work.

Note, $E(X)=E(XI(X=0))+E(XI(X>0))$

$=0+E(XI(X>0))=E(XI(X>0))\leq \sqrt{E(X^2)}\sqrt{E(I(X>0)^2)}=\sqrt{E(X^2)P(X>0)}$

Hence, $P(X>0)\geq \dfrac{(E(X))^2}{E(X^2)}$

Comment: Can you please explain why $E(X_i (X > 0)) \leq \sqrt{E[X^2]} \sqrt(E(I(X > 0)^2))$?

Comment: @FalsePromise This is [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/261116/250955).

Comment: Apply the CS inequality as @ZoranLoncarevic mentioned, in the form $E(AB)\leq \sqrt{E(A^2)E(B^2)}$ for random variables $A,B$. Here, $A=X$ and $B=I(X>0)$.

Comment: By the way, I would like to point out that in the question first posted, it was not mentioned that $X$ is discrete. Therefore, I wrote the first line of my answer.

Comment: @LandonCarter $I(X > 0)$ is some indicator function, which returns 1, if $x > 0$ and $0$ otherwise?
P.S. Sorry, I forgot to mention that it is a discrete variable.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You are correct. Note that this proof is general. But you can do something. Replicate this proof in the discrete case. See if you can write the things down. That is, write $E(X)=\sum_{k=0}^n kP(X=k)$, etc.

Comment: @LandonCarter I'm really sorry, but I don't get why $E(X)=E(XI(X=0))+E(XI(X>0))$. $E[I] = Pr[X > 0]$, so if $X$ and $I(X>0)$ are independent(are they?) then $E[XI] = E[X]E[I] = E[X]Pr[X > 0] \neq E[X]$.

Comment: No, $X$ and $I(X>0)$ are not at all independent! Let us call for brevity $I(X>0)=B$. Then note that $B=1$ if $X>0$ and $B=0$ otherwise. So there is a clear dependence of $B$ on $X$.