# Conditional Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality

Tags: probability-theory, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $X, Y, Z$ be r.v.s. I wish to show that $E(XY|Z)^2 \leq E(X^2|Z)E(Y^2|Z)$ almost surely.

I can easily adapt the proof of the unconditional Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, shown in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261112/prove-that-random-variables-satisfy-the-inequality-exy2-le-ex2ey2), and so get that
$$E((X+tY)^2|Z) = t^2\underbrace{E(Y^2|Z)}_{A} + 2t\underbrace{E(XY|Z)}_{B} + \underbrace{E(X^2|Z)}_{C} \geq 0 \text{ almost surely}.$$
Moreover, $Y^2 \geq 0$ implies that the coefficient $A = E(Y^2|Z) \geq 0$ almost surely. To conclude the proof, I wish to make use of the well-known **Fact** that "if  $a \geq 0$, a polynomial $at^2 + bt + c \geq 0$ if and only if its discriminant $b^2 - 4ac \leq 0$."

However, I only know of the premise, that the coefficient $$A = E(Y^2|Z) \geq 0$$ and the quadratic in $t$, $$t^2E(Y^2|Z) + 2tE(XY|Z) + E(X^2|Z)\geq 0$$ are true *almost surely* and not absolutely. Is it still appropriate to make use of this **Fact**. If so, is it true to state that the conclusion, $B^2 - 4AC \leq 0$ must hold *almost surely*?

Comment: The CS inequality follows immediately from the unconditional, provided you are willing to use regular conditional probability. But to answer your question, yes.